# Show only current directory, not all path and use them in makefile to tar in c

Tags: makefile, tar

I want to create "make tar" to make tar.gz file from the directory
I do this

```
KATBIEZ = `basename $(PWD)`
```

Then I clean because I don't want to have .o i .x file, only c

```
clean:
    rm -f a.out *~ *.o *.x
```

And this is ma make tar

```
tar: clean
    (cd ..; tar cvzf $(KATBIEZ).tar.gz $(KATBIEZ); ls -altr)
```

The problem is that in $(KATBIEZ) I have for example "home/Mark/New_Folder/Program10" I want to have only Program10/

So instead of

```
cd ..; tar cvzf `basename home/Mark/New_Folder/Program10`.tar.gz `basenamehome/Mark/New_Folder/Program10`; ls -altr
```

I want to have

```
cd ..; tar cvzf Program10.tar.gz Program10/; ls -altr
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Does something not work?  If it doesn't work, please specify exactly what doesn't work and what happens.  Or does it work but you just don't want to see the basename command in the output that make is printing?  Because, as far as I can tell the _result_ of running both the commands you have here is the same.

Comment: It's not working MadScientist. I cant tar, archive is empty, when I run this

Comment: Something is odd here then: the way you've shown this is missing some critical information.  I'm assuming that the typos in your quoted examples above (missing space in _basenamehome/Mark/New_Folder/Program10_ etc.) are not really in your environment (it's much, much better to cut and paste directly than to retype by hand).  Are you using symbolic links?  As far as I can see the two commands you show above give identical results.  If you type either of the two above commands at your shell prompt do you get the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to run `basename` :

```
KATBIEZ=$(shell basename "$(PWD)")
```

To trouble-shoot, run this makefile :

```
KATBIEZ=$(shell basename "$(PWD)")

tar:
    ( cd ..; echo tar cvzf "$(KATBIEZ).tar.gz" "$(KATBIEZ)"; ls -altr )
```

and paste result.

Comment: it's not working. basename: excess argument „C/Program10/nowy/Program10”
It said that It wont make empty archive

Comment: translate to english
basename: excess argument „C/Program10/new/Program10”
Write „basename --help” for more information.
basename: excess argument „C/Program10/new/Program10”
Napisz „basename --help” dla uzyskania informacji.
(cd ..; tar cvzf .tar.gz ; ls -altr)
tar: Cowardly, I refuse to use an empty archive
Use "tar --help" or "tar --usage" to get more
information.
together 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 jakub jakub 4096 maj  1 20:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 jakub jakub 4096 maj  1 22:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 jakub jakub 4096 maj  1 22:24 Program10